# Add checkbox in Yii2 GridView filtering

Tags: yii2

I'm using Yii2 and I want to add a checkbox filter for a boolean variables in a `GridView` search. This is my rules from `ModelSearch`:

```
public function rules()
{
     return [
         [['bool1','bool2','bool3','bool4'],'boolean']
     ];
}
```

So, how can I render as a checkbox instead of text input?

These are my `GridView` parameters:

```
$paramsCustom = [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn'],
            [ 
                //boolean column
                'attribute' => 'bool1',
                'label' => 'S',
                'format' => 'raw',
                'value' => function ($model, $index, $widget) {
                     ....           
                },
            ],
```

My `bool1` attribute is boolean. So, in the `GridView` filtering appears a text input, and I want to filter the results displayed in the `GridView` using a checkbox instead a text input.

This is my `GridView` column:

[image: This is my GridView column]

Comment: what you have done so far..

Comment: What? I don't follow you..

Comment: can you show us some code that you did..

Comment: Question edited.

Comment: well in that case you can go for select list with options.. if you want to display checkboxes in options list you need to take help of plugin or need some custom code

Comment: Thanks Nitin Pund. Solved using a dropdown: 

[ 
    'attribute' => 'bool1',
    'label' => 'W',
    'format' => 'html',
    'value' => function ($model, $index, $widget) {
     ...
    },
                                'filter' => [
                                    '0' => 'Yes',
                                    '1' => 'No',
                                ]
    
   ],

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using checkbox for filtering usually does not make much sense, since checkbox can represent only two states: checked or unchecked. However for filtering you actually need three states:

1. only checked,
2. only unchecked,
3. all (no filtering).

You should probably use dropdown in this case:

```
[ 
    'attribute' => 'bool1',
    'label' => 'S',
    'format' => 'raw',
    'value' => function ($model, $index, $widget) {
         ....           
    },
    'filter' => [1 => 'Yes', 0 => 'No'], 
],
```

It will generate three options: "Yes", "No" and empty default position for disabling filtering.